# Approach to read data from Oracle DB & Present it like HTML (UI)

Tags: python, java, node.js, angularjs, oracle

I would like to read data from an Oracle database and need to present a report in the browser (like HTML or other UI technology)

What would be the best approach to do this?

I'm thinking of these approaches:

1. JDBC (To read from Oracle) & Java Script to present
2. NodeJS (`node-oracledb` driver) & AngularJS to present
3. Python (`cx_Oracle` to interact with DB) & Flask to present it to browser

What would be the best approach among these?

Would something else be better than any of these.

Comment: is PHP an option?

Comment: You have forgotten CGI, Perl, Java, ColdFusion, Flash, serving PDF files, <insert other language here> and also just presenting it using plain HTML without JavaScript ... and this is also off topic for StackOverflow as answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: @MT0, I agree that there are tons of other languages and technologies available in the market today to handle such cases.
But I've posted here as we have quite cognoscenti audience on this platform where users can learn from tech savvy people as to what would be the best way to implement keeping in mind the best practices.

Answer (score 0):

> JDBC (To read from Oracle) & Java Script to present

"Java Script" is one word: JavaScript.

> What would be the best approach to do this?

"best" is relative and subjective. Let's start with this: Do you know Java, JavaScript, or Python? Start with the one you know best. Build something and then reevaluate based on what you know.

Don't know any of those? I'd start with Node.js - but I'm biased! :) The Node.js community is pretty awesome and it helps to only need one language in the front-end and mid-tier environments.

If you're new to JavaScript, reconsider AngularJS (the community favors TypeScript so you'll be pushed to adopt that too). Take a look at Vue.js instead: https://vuejs.org/

Comment: Haters gonna hate.

Comment: @haifzhan Yes you're right!
Haters gonna hate no matter what we do.

Comment: Thanks @DanMcGhan I've edited question. I have Java background but I'm open for anything as long as it is faster & less cumbersome.

Comment: I see. Then definitely try Node.js w/node-oracledb in the mid-tier and Vue.js for the front-end. Have fun! You might find this useful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tSW72IlTJGw Slides and code are here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7x7rwk3u03aas86/Making%20RESTful%20Web%20Services%20the%20Easy%20Way%20with%20Node.js.zip?dl=0